option pricing under perpetual features long and short funding rate
We have perpetual futures market and we want to use it for hedging our option.
On perpetual futures you pay long funding fee, if you go long or short funding fee if you go short. (The funding fee can be negative, which means you are getting paid)
Most often the long funding + short funding != 0.
How can you price an option
The first idea
is to use BSM with dividends and use q=- funding rate.
Due to the fact we have 2 funding rates we can compute the ASK/BID price based on long or short position on the given option.
For example as MM I calculate quotes:

ASK price of call option -  I need hedge long delta to be delta neutral - pay long funding rate. So use BSM with q=-long funding rate.
BID price of call option - I need hedge short delta to be delta neutral - pay short funding rate. So use BSM with q=-short funding rate.

In opposite way it applies to PUT.
Is this a good way to price the option ASK and BID? We assume, we know the IV and r.
